# Null Reference Exception in Unity game engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to go through a tutorial on Unity (Will Goldstone's book 3.x Game Development Essentials) and keep running into an error messages and I just can't figure out what is wrong with my code. It's from Chapter 5, I am writing this in Javascript. For what i can see I have everything correct--the null reference comes up in my OpenDoor function line 2 & in my shutDoor function line2.:

> Null Reference Exception 
>   PlayerCollisionsjs.OpenDoor(UnityEngine.GameObject door) (at Assests/Scripts
>   /PlayerCollisionsjs.js: 47 **and 37 the lines refecenced below).

What am I missing? My `OpenDoor` & `CloseDoor` sounds are loaded and the code works if I remove the shut Door requests...any thought

```
#pragma strict

private var doorIsOpen : boolean = false;
private var doorTimer : float = 0.0;
private var currentDoor : GameObject;


var doorOpenTime : float = 3.0;
var doorOpenSound : AudioClip;
var doorShutSound : AudioClip;

function Start () {

}

 function Update () {

    if(doorIsOpen) { doorTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if(doorTimer > doorOpenTime) {
        shutDoor(currentDoor);
        doorTimer = 0.0f;
      }
    }
 }

function OnControllerColliderHit(hit : ControllerColliderHit){

        if(hit.gameObject.tag == "playerDoor" && doorIsOpen == false) {
        currentDoor == hit.gameObject;
        OpenDoor(hit.gameObject);
        OpenDoor(currentDoor);
      }

  }

function OpenDoor(door: GameObject) {

    doorIsOpen = true;
    door.audio.PlayOneShot(doorOpenSound);
    door.transform.parent.animation.Play("dooropen");   
}


function shutDoor(door : GameObject) {

    doorIsOpen = false;
    door.audio.PlayOneShot(doorShutSound);
    door.transform.parent.animation.Play("doorshut");
}
```

I did see that someone else got stuck on the same code, but we don't have the same problem, my audio works before I insert the shutDoor function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not assign open and shut door sounds to above two audio clips, 1st assign these sounds to your variables then your error will be finished.